# CakePHP plugin localization in different files

Tags: cakephp, localization, cakephp-3.0

I've made ContentManager plugin for my cakephp (3.2) apps. It has base translation file in `/plugins/ContentManager/src/Locale/ru/content_manager.po`.

Now I want to add some additions translations on application level. So I need some additional `po` file for my plugin. If I put one more `content_manager.po`  file in `app\src\Locale\ru` folder, it overrides base file.

Is it possible to add file like `content_manager.0.po, content_manager.base.po` or something, and make whem work together? Anyway I need to extend plugin transalations somehow.

base file contains strings like these

```
msgid "tab_MenuItems"
msgid "content.type.News"
msgid "users.role.admin"
```

and so on.
Additional file contains application-specific strings like:

```
msgid "content.type.Products"
msgid "content.type.Orders"
msgid "users.role.manager"
```

plugin itself uses translations like (*example*, `smarty`) this:

```
{foreach $registered_types as $ct}
<li>{__d("content_manager", "content.type.$ct")}</li>
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `default.po` file in your apps `ru` locale folder, this file will by default be used by the so called "fallback loader", which is going to be used in case the requested message ID cannot be found in the primary domain, ie in `content_manager.po`.

In case you need more control, you can always build custom loaders/packages, like for example:

```
use Cake\I18n\I18n;
use Cake\I18n\MessagesFileLoader;

I18n::config('content_manager', function ($name, $locale) {
    $fileLoader = new MessagesFileLoader('content_manager', $locale, 'po');

    /* @var $package \Aura\Intl\Package  */
    $package = $fileLoader();
    $package->setFallback('content_manager.base');

    return $package;
});
```

This would create a loader that internally pre-loads the default `content_manager` domain messages, and set the fallback loader domain to `content_manager.base`, so that it would try to load messages from your `content_manager.base.po` file in case there's no translation present in the default domain.

And don't forget to clear the cache (`tmp/cache/persistent`) after adding/modifying translations/loaders.

See also

- **[Cookbook > Internationalization & Localization > Creating Generic Translators](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#creating-generic-translators)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\I18n::config()](https://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.I18n.I18n.html#_config)**
- **[API > \Cake\I18n\MessagesFileLoader](https://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.I18n.MessagesFileLoader.html#___construct)**

Comment: yes, sure I can use `default.po`, but it is not good solution in my case, as it is used for other translations and I don't want to mix them. I've read a bit about fallback, but haven't tried to use it yet. Thanks, I'll check it tomorrow

Comment: hm, using this code, loader tries to find `base` file in `src/Locale` folder, and doesn't search in plugins folder.

Comment: it looks like I should implement my own `MessagesFileLoad` class for `base` translation domain and override `translationsFolders` method

Comment: @teran I cannot confirm that, for me the shown example looks up the `content_manager.base.po` file on app level, and the `content_manager.po` file on plugin level as expected. **https://gist.github.com/ndm2/91723951e76f7331b685e99b3677c637**

Comment: I  have `base` file in plugin's folder. I've added new messageLoader class for `base` domain, It works fine. Of course, may be, I shoud leave `content_manager.po` with base-translations in plugin's folder and add some `content_manager.ext.po` to app-level locales folder. The idea was that end user adds new translation file on app-level named like a plugin itself. So, It's a naming logic question, I'll think about it, there are few ways to solve this task (at least 3: rename and move files; add new loader class;  and change `__d` calls to `base` in plugin).  Everything works fine, thanks!